# Database design for CRM User table for a specific scenario

Tags: sql, database, database-design, crm

I'm designing a database for our CRM system and need some help with the CRM User table.

Types of users:

1. Admin
2. Sales Reps from Branch 2
3. Sales Reps from Branch 3
4. Client login

Now for this scenario would it make sense to have all users in a single table and have a table attribute called "type" to identify the type of user? OR should I have a seperate table for each type of user? Also, there will be some information sharing between the Sales reps.

Comment: Can you provide some more information? At the moment, this question is pretty vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, I usually go with one `User` table with a `Type` associated with it. If you have additional Sales Rep attributes you want to store, create a `SalesRep` table with a foreign key back to the `User` table. Then, create a view that joins `User` and `SalesRep`, so it looks, logically, like there's just a `usvSalesRep` table that has all of the attributes you need for Sales Reps.

But, this depends a lot on data volume and transaction load, so additional information you can supply there is useful.

Comment: There is less than 100 users and less than 1000 transactions a day. The SalesRep will have some extra attributes like how many sales they closed in so and so year, how many bids are out there and baically some performance attributes.

Comment: @mvador99 - Single table can what you need without an issue, then :)

Comment: foreign keys for those tables or vice versa :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the number of users that you expect.

But usually a single table is enought.

---

If you'll have billions of users maybe you can do [horizontal partitioning](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/partitioning-the-data-in-a-table) and make multiple tables.

Comment: Its less than a 1000 users. I guess single table it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Single table should be fine. And I disagree that the number users really have much impact on its design in this case.

Whenever possible, you should design your tables to mimick real life. Admin, Sales Rep, etc are just descriptions/attributes of who they are.  Ultimately, they are all "People"... or User.  So having one "User" table with "Admin", "SalesRep" as attibutes makes sense to me.  Use the "Type" approach only if the user can only be one "Type".  Use separate columns if they can be multiple user types. Ie. one can be a SalesRepBranch2 and SalesRepBranch3 at the same time.  Might consider normalizing this even further.